# NDK step-by-step debugging with Android Studio 2.0 (Beta 2)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I tried [the experimental Gradle Plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) with Android Studio 1.5 as I was hoping it to enable the NDK step-by-step debugging. It didn't.

As migrating from the regular to the experimental build system requires quite a lot of work, I am trying to figure out whether this debugging support had been enabled with the Android Studio 2.0 beta, before trying again.

This paragraph of the documentation is unclear to me:

> **Multiple NDK Projects**
>
> Plugin 0.4.0 added the preliminary support for NDK dependencies and
>   the ability to create just a native library.  Please be aware this is
>   a preview of the direction we are going and the implementation is not
>   complete.  *Note that while it is possible to compile the native
>   project for Gradle, editing and debugging support in Android Studio is
>   not yet implemented*.

The last part that I highlighted in italic says debugging is not enabled, but this is in the **Multiple NDK Projects** section. Does it apply to all configurations or just to projects with multiple NDK dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in Android Studio 2.2, but [only for 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754201/840960). The deprecated NDK toolchain must be replaced by [CMake](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) in the project configuration.