# How to install the Android Studio 2.2 CMake package/tool?

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake, android-studio-2.2

My recent Android Studio 2.2 preview 3 installation can't seem to find CMake.

I tried installing it from the SDK Tools but there's no such package...

[image]

Comment: Okay, CMake is only available for 64 bit machine:  <host-bits>64</host-bits>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We won't be able to support CMake (or ndk-build) on 32 bit OS because it is not supported in CLion which is the tech we use for the C++ editor. The root cause is memory\address-space limits.

Here's a helper page where I describe Android Studio C++ support including the 64 bit requirement: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/external-c-builds

I hope this helps!
- Jomo

Comment: Well, it does and it doesn't :)