# CMake Cannot be found in SDK Manager Tools

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFTPe.jpg]

Couldn't find Cmake In SDK tools . So i have manually added to SDK Folder and run the project and i am getting an error: How to get cmake and run the project without error ?? Help ...

Comment: Have you tried to google? E.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37754201/3440745) tells that 32-bit OS doesn't have CMake.

Comment: Yeah right..!! 32-Bit doesn't have CMake. To make it appear you need to go to the android file location path and open 64 bit of Android Application file and you can see Cmake in that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the Android Studio 2.2 CMake package/tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740147/how-to-install-the-android-studio-2-2-cmake-package-tool)

Answer (score 1):

@Tsyvarev: Instead of opening the application in blue color i have opened the application in red color(64-bit) then i am able to see CMAKE in Android SDK Tools. 
Click the below image:

[CMAKE ONLY APPEARS ON 64-BIT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLYO3.jpg)

Comment: Worked for me...Thanks alot